# iOS - Update the icon badge number at a certain time after the application closes

Tags: swift, swiftui, notifications, background

for example, it's 15:00 and I'm closing the app. icon badge number is 3.
At exactly 15:20, icon badge number should become 4.

What are the possible solutions?

Swift/SwiftUI

I read about background tasks, but it doesn't seem to solve the problem, because the task happens when the system decides

Answer (score 1):

You can use notification to achieve what you want, and I consider that you want to increase the badge number without any other interactions, then I implement silent notification:

```
func scheduleSilentNotification() {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.sound = .none
    content.body = ""
    content.userInfo = ["silent": true]

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 20 * 60, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "silentNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error scheduling silent notification: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

and you should call this inside the `applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication)` function of `AppDelegate`.

For increasing the badge number you can handle it like below in `AppDelegate`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // Check if the notification is silent
    if let notification = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: Any], let sound = notification["sound"] as? String, sound == "default" {
        // This is a silent notification
        print("Received a silent notification")
        
        // Increase the badge number by one
        if let currentBadgeNumber = application.applicationIconBadgeNumber {
            application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = currentBadgeNumber + 1
        } else {
            application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
        }

        // Perform the necessary background tasks

        // Call the completion handler when finished
        completionHandler(.newData)
    } else {
        // This is a regular notification with a sound
        // Handle it as needed
    }
}
```

Comment: `didReceiveRemoteNotification` won't be triggered for local notifications.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri you're right. Is there a same thing for local notifications?

Comment: unfortunately no, at least not until user tapped on the notification, we don't get callbacks for local notifications when app is killed.